# How to write a really complicated formula into mathematica and do symbolic computation?

Tags: symbolic

I want write the following formula $a$ into mathematica and do symbolic computation like $a^2$. $a$ is defined as follows:
\begin{multline*}
a=\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}f_1^2(t)+11\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}f_2^2(t)+\\
\sum_{t=0}^T\mathbb{I}[n_{t+1}>0]\sum_{\tau =0}^{n_{t+1}-1}g_1^2(t,\tau)+11\sum_{t=0}^{T}\mathbb{I}[n_{t+1}>0]\sum_{\tau=0}^{n_{t+1}-1}g_2^2(t,\tau),
\end{multline*}

where $\mathbb{I}[\cdot]$ is the indicator function, $n$ is a vetor, $n_{t}$ means the t-th element of $n$, which starts from 0, and $T$ is a integer.

$f_1(t), f_2(t), g_1(t,\tau), g_2(t,\tau)$ are defined below:

\begin{align*} 
    f_1(t) &= \operatorname{logit}\left(\frac{\alpha+t}{\alpha+\beta+(\sum_{\tau=0}^{t}n_{\tau+1})+t}\right)\\
    f_2(t) &= \operatorname{logit}\left(\frac{\alpha+t}{\alpha+\beta+t}\right)\\
    g_1(t,\tau)&=\operatorname{logit}\left(\frac{\alpha+t}{\alpha+\beta+(\sum_{t'=1}^{t}n_{t'})+t+\tau}\right)\\
    g_2(t, \tau)&=\operatorname{logit}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta+(\sum_{t'=0}^{t}n_{t'})+\tau}\right),
\end{align*}

where $\alpha, \beta$ are integer, $n_0$ is defined as 0 to make the formula more clean, and $\operatorname{logit}(x)=\operatorname{log}(\frac{x}{1-x})$.

An example is shown below: when $T=2,\alpha=9,\beta=1, n=[0,0,0,1]^T$, $a=180.41$.

I will really appreciate it if anybody could help me out of this problem, which troubles me for a long time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it has troubled you for a long time, then can we please see your attempt(s) pasted as Mathematica code?

Comment: Can you clarify two things: 1) in g1 and g2, do the sums include the $ + t + \tau$ in g1 and the $+\tau$ in g2 ? i.e please put parentheses around the part which is summed over, and 2) in g2 you are running the sum over $t^\prime = 0$ to $t$ but that will give $n_0$ which doesn't exist - it must go from 1 to 4 - shouldn't this sum be from 1 to t ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Since I am a beginner in Mathematica, and although I have read many posts of symbolic computation in Mathematica, I still cannot find a way out to write effective Mathematica code. @Syed

Comment: Thanks for your comment to point out my problem @flinty! The two things you mentioned have been clarified in the question. Besides, since $n_0=0$, $n$ will always have $T+2$ entries, which is shown in the example.

Comment: @Guanting Wu, graduate students need to be independent learners, problem solvers and resourceful, not to mention systematic. I hope you get a good book on Mathematica and start there. Here I am assuming of course that you are a graduate student. The other possibility suggested by the complexity of the equations is that you work at a company, in which case there need be no sympathy for you, whether you are a new user or not.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your example $T = 2$, $\alpha = 9$, $\beta = 1$, $n = [0, 0, 0, 1]^T$ gives $a = 12 [\log^2(9) + \log^2(10)] \approx 121.556$. In this case, $n$ has no effect on $a$ because the first 3 elements are zero and all the sums about elements of $n$ and the indicator functions vanish.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @tueda! Actually, the $n_3$ in the example will have effect on the last two terms of $a$ since $n_{T+1}=n_3=1$.

Comment: @GuantingWu Oh, does your indexing starts from 0 (instead of 1)? Mathematica uses the 1-based indexing for lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is natural to follow the functional programming approach in Mathematica. Here is a straightforward implementation, where what you need are all expressed by defining functions:

```
logit[x_] := Log[x / (1 - x)];

f1[t_, alpha_, beta_, n_List] := logit[
  (alpha + t) / (alpha + beta + Sum[n[[tau + 1]], {tau, 0, t}] + t)
];

f2[t_, alpha_, beta_, n_List] := logit[
  (alpha + t) / (alpha + beta + t)
];

g1[t_, tau_, alpha_, beta_, n_List] := logit[
  (alpha + t) / (alpha + beta + Sum[n[[tt]], {tt, 1, t}] + t + tau)
];

g2[t_, tau_, alpha_, beta_, n_List] := logit[
  alpha / (alpha + beta + Sum[n[[tt]], {tt, 1, t}] + tau)
];

a[T_, alpha_, beta_, n_List] := (
  Sum[f1[t, alpha, beta, n]^2, {t, 0, T - 1}]
  + 11 Sum[f2[t, alpha, beta, n]^2, {t, 0, T - 1}]
  + Sum[If[n[[t + 1]] > 0,
      Sum[g1[t, tau, alpha, beta, n]^2, {tau, 0, n[[t + 1]] - 1}]
      , 0]
    , {t, 0, T}]
  + 11 Sum[If[n[[t + 1]] > 0,
      Sum[g2[t, tau, alpha, beta, n]^2, {tau, 0, n[[t + 1]] - 1}]
      , 0]
    , {t, 0, T}]
);
```

I appended arguments `alpha`, `beta`, `n` to the `f1`, ..., `g2` functions (though `f2` doesn't use `n`). Mathematica uses the 1-based indexing, and so `n` should be given as a list with this convention. Because $n_0 = 0$, I changed the lower bound of the sum in the $g_2$ from $0$ to $1$.

Example:

```
a[2, 9, 1, {0, 0, 1}] // Simplify
% // N
```

gives

```
23*Log[9]^2 + 12*Log[10]^2 + Log[11]^2
180.412
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @tueda! Your answer is perfect at numerical computation. However, if I want to do symbolic computation like $a^2$, it does not work out. Besides, I mainly want $T,n$ to be unknown variables.

Comment: @GuantingWu Then, well, it depends on your exact situation, but if you don't like to see errors for symbolic `T`, you can write the pattern for `a` as `a[T_Integer, alpha_?NumericQ, beta_?NumericQ, n_List] := ( ...` to restrict `T` to be an integer, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your time @tueda! I think the 'If' statement seems not good at symbolic computation. I will try other ways around.